# Does a Universal Link persists POST data?

Tags: ios, swift, xamarin.ios, ios-universal-links, handoff

I need to get the POST data for a Universal Link.  How do I capture this in iOS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not possible. The only info passed through in `continueUserActivity` is the string of the URL that was requested (with any parameters appended to it).